# How do I discover the PCIe bus topology and slot numbers on the board?

Tags: c++, windows, cuda, pci, pci-e

For example, when I use multi-GPU system with CUDA C/C++ and GPUDirect 2.0 P2P, and I use nested PCI-Express Switches, as shown on picture, then I must know how many switches between any two GPUs by their PCI Bus ID, to optimize data transfer and distribution of calculation.

Or if I already know hardware PCIe topology with PCIe-switches, then I must know, to which hardware PCIe slot on board is connected any GPU card.
[image]

As I know, even if I already know hardware PCIe topology with PCIe-switches, then these identifiers is not hard-bound to PCIe slots on the board, and these IDs may change and be different from run to run of system:

- CUDA device_id
- nvidia-smi/nvml GPU id
- PCI Bus ID

What is the best way to discover the topology of the PCIe bus with detailed device tree and the number of PCIe slot on the board **on Windows and Linux**?

Comment: @Robert Crovella Thank you. But `nvidia-smi topo` works only on Linux, and **not on Windows - but I need it**. And `nvidia-smi topo -m` shows only 4 values between any 2 GPUs, which shows **number of PCI-Switches**: SOC (**0** + QPI), PHB(**0**), PXB(**1 or more**), PIX(**1 internal**). But if I have topology with 2, 3 or more levels of PCIe-Switches, then I can't use it.

Comment: Maybe you should be talking to your system vendor. They might have a proprietary hardware abstraction layer or library you could use. The types of system architectures you are asking about are pretty exotic and out of the realms of most standard setups and tools.

Answer (score 7):

PCI devices (endpoints) have a unique address. This address has 3 parts:

- BusID
- DeviceID
- FunctionID

For example function 3 of device 12 on bus 3 is written in BDF notion: `03:0C.3`. An extended BDF notation adds a domain (mostly 0000) as a prefix: `0000:03:0c.3`.

Linux lists these devices in `/sys/bus/pci/devices`

```
paebbels@debian8:~$ ll /sys/bus/pci/devices/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 0 Aug  5 15:14 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:00:00.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:00:01.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:00:07.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:00:07.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:00:18.6 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:18.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:00:18.7 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:18.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:02:00.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:02:01.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:01.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:02:02.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:02:03.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 11:44 0000:03:00.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0
```

Here you can see that sys-fs lists devices 00 to 03 of bus 02 as connected to bus 00, device 11, function 0

From these information, you can rebuilt the complete PCI bus-tree. The tree is always the same after a boot up, unless you add or remove devices.

The windows device manager offers the same information. The property dialog shows you the device type, vendor and location: e.g. `PCI bus 0, device 2, function 0` for an integrated Intel HD 4600 graphics.

Currently, I don't know how you can get these information by scripting or programming language in a Windows environment, but there are commercial and free tools in the internet, that provide these information. Maybe there is an API.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version of the script that does not need to parse the registry. All of the information (used here) is available within win32_pnpentity.

```
Function Get-BusFunctionID { 

    gwmi -namespace root\cimv2 -class Win32_PnPEntity |% {

        if ($_.PNPDeviceID -like "PCI\*") {

            $locationInfo = $_.GetDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo').deviceProperties.Data

            if ($locationInfo -match 'PCI bus (\d+), device (\d+), function (\d+)') {

                new-object psobject -property @{ 
                    "Name"       = $_.Name
                    "PnPID"      = $_.PNPDeviceID
                    "BusID"      = $matches[1]
                    "DeviceID"   = $matches[2]
                    "FunctionID" = $matches[3]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use e.g.: the following Powershell-Script with the devcon.exe tool from the Windows Device Driver Kit:

```
Function Get-BusFunctionID { 
    $Devices = .\devcon.exe find PCI\*

    for($i=0; $i -lt $Devices.length; $i++) { 

        if(!($Devices[$i] -match "PCI\\*")) {
            continue
        }
        $DevInfo = $Devices[$i].split(":")
        $deviceId = $DevInfo[0]
        $locationInfo = (get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$deviceID" -name locationinformation).locationINformation

        $businfo = Resolve-PCIBusInfo -locationInfo $locationinfo 

        new-object psobject -property @{ 
            "Name"        = $DevInfo[1];
            "PnPID"       = $DevInfo[0]
            "PCIBusID"      = $businfo.BusID; 
            "PCIDeviceID"   = $businfo.DeviceID; 
            "PCIFunctionID" = $businfo.FunctionID 
        } 
    }
}

Function Resolve-PCIBusInfo { 

param ( 
[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] 
[string] 
$locationInfo 
) 
PROCESS { 
[void]($locationInfo -match  "\d+,\d+,\d+")
$busId,$deviceID,$functionID = $matches[0] -split "," 

new-object psobject -property @{ 
          "BusID" = $busID; 
          "DeviceID" = "$deviceID" 
          "FunctionID" = "$functionID" 
          } 
}          
}
```

Usage example:

```
Get-BusFunctionID | Where-Object {$_.PCIBusID -eq 0 -and $_.PCIDeviceID -eq 0} | Format-Table
Get-BusFunctionID | Sort-Object PCIBusID, PCIDeviceID, PCIFunctionID | Format-Table -GroupBy PCIBusID
Get-BusFunctionID | Sort-Object PCIBusID, PCIDeviceID, PCIFunctionID | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows a ready to run Powershell-script:

```
Function Get-BusFunctionID { 
    #gwmi -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity"
    $Devices = get-wmiobject -namespace root\cimv2 -class Win32_PnPEntity

    for($i=0; $i -lt $Devices.length; $i++) { 

        if(!($Devices[$i].PNPDeviceID -match "PCI\\*")) {
            continue
        }
        $deviceId = $Devices[$i].PNPDeviceID
        $locationInfo = (get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$deviceID" -name locationinformation).locationINformation

        $businfo = Resolve-PCIBusInfo -locationInfo $locationinfo 

        new-object psobject -property @{ 
            "Name"        = $Devices[$i].Name;
            "PnPID"       = $Devices[$i].PNPDeviceID
            "PCIBusID"      = $businfo.BusID; 
            "PCIDeviceID"   = $businfo.DeviceID; 
            "PCIFunctionID" = $businfo.FunctionID 
        } 
    }
}

Function Resolve-PCIBusInfo { 

param ( 
[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] 
[string] 
$locationInfo 
) 
PROCESS { 
[void]($locationInfo -match  "\d+,\d+,\d+")
$busId,$deviceID,$functionID = $matches[0] -split "," 

new-object psobject -property @{ 
          "BusID" = $busID; 
          "DeviceID" = "$deviceID" 
          "FunctionID" = "$functionID" 
          } 
}          
}
```

Usage example:

```
Get-BusFunctionID | Where-Object {$_.PCIBusID -eq 0 -and $_.PCIDeviceID -eq 0} | Format-Table
Get-BusFunctionID | Sort-Object PCIBusID, PCIDeviceID, PCIFunctionID | Format-Table -GroupBy
```

Answer (score 1):

For network adapters, starting with Windows 8 or Windows 2012, you can use WMI class [`MSFT_NetAdapterHardwareInfoSettingData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/netadaptercimprov/msft-netadapterhardwareinfosettingdata):

```
gwmi -Namespace root\standardcimv2 MSFT_NetAdapterHardwareInfoSettingData | Format-Table Description,BusNumber,DeviceNumber,FunctionNumber

Description                        BusNumber DeviceNumber FunctionNumber
-----------                        --------- ------------ --------------
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #6         0           17              0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #3         0            9              0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #5         0           16              0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #2         0            8              0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #7         0           18              0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #8         0           19              0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter            0            3              0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #4         0           10              0
```

...or PowerShell command [`Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapterhardwareinfo?view=winserver2012-ps):

```
Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo | Format-Table Description,Bus,Device,Function

Description                        Bus Device Function
-----------                        --- ------ --------
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #6   0     17        0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #3   0      9        0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #5   0     16        0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #2   0      8        0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #7   0     18        0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #8   0     19        0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter      0      3        0
Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #4   0     10        0
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows device id and function are also encoded in the last part of `PNPDeviceID`, which is easier to get. However, the way they're encoded is not documented.

Example: `PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_2829&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_02\\3&267A616A&0&68`.

`68` (hex) may be *device* number 13 (dec) shifted by 3 bits to the left, while the last 3 bits may be the *function* number 0.
As *function* is usually 0, you may notice that most values of `PNPDeviceID` end with `0` or `8`. 3 bits offset may come from [`CONFIG_ADDRESS` PCI register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Software_implementation):

> The format of CONFIG_ADDRESS is the following:
>
> 0x80000000 | bus << 16 | device << 11 | function <<  8 | offset

See also [Intel chipset documentation](http://www.csit-sun.pub.ro/~cpop/Documentatie_SMP/Intel_Microprocessor_Systems/Intel_ProcessorNew/Intel%20White%20Paper/Accessing%20PCI%20Express%20Configuration%20Registers%20Using%20Intel%20Chipsets.pdf), page 5:

> 2. The device’s “PCI device number” must be written into bits [15:11] of
>      I/O location CF8h

`0` before `68` may indicate *bus* number.

Answer (score 0):

Among device properties of `WMI_PnPDevice`, in registry key or in the output of `devcon.exe`, there is [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-address) property. It's 32-bit integer (`DWORD`) in which higher 16 bits are device number and lower 16 bits are function number:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> (gwmi win32_pnpEntity).getDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_Device_Address').deviceProperties | ?{$_.data} | Format-Table DeviceID,keyName,{$_.data -shr 16},{$_.data -band 0xFFFF}

DeviceID                                                               keyName                $_.data -shr 16 $_.data -band 0xFFFF
--------                                                               -------                --------------- --------------------
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_7000&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&08           DEVPKEY_Device_Address               1                    0
STORAGE\VOLUME\{EF420E5C-5744-11E9-92B5-806E6F6E6963}#0000000000100000 DEVPKEY_Device_Address               0                    1
PCI\VEN_80EE&DEV_CAFE&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&20           DEVPKEY_Device_Address               4                    0
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2829&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_02\3&267A616A&0&68           DEVPKEY_Device_Address              13                    0
SCSI\DISK&VEN_VBOX&PROD_HARDDISK\4&2617AEAE&0&000000                   DEVPKEY_Device_Address               0                65535
PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1000&SUBSYS_00011AF4&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&18           DEVPKEY_Device_Address               3                    0
PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1000&SUBSYS_00011AF4&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&40           DEVPKEY_Device_Address               8                    0
PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1000&SUBSYS_00011AF4&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&48           DEVPKEY_Device_Address               9                    0
PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1000&SUBSYS_00011AF4&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&50           DEVPKEY_Device_Address              10                    0
PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1000&SUBSYS_00011AF4&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&80           DEVPKEY_Device_Address              16                    0
PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1000&SUBSYS_00011AF4&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&88           DEVPKEY_Device_Address              17                    0
PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1000&SUBSYS_00011AF4&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&90           DEVPKEY_Device_Address              18                    0
PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1000&SUBSYS_00011AF4&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&98           DEVPKEY_Device_Address              19                    0
PCI\VEN_80EE&DEV_BEEF&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00\3&267A616A&0&10           DEVPKEY_Device_Address               2                    0
SCSI\CDROM&VEN_VBOX&PROD_CD-ROM\4&2617AEAE&0&010000                    DEVPKEY_Device_Address               1                65535
```

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21852454/1833960) about the meaning of address and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903164/1833960).
My [answer on related question](https://superuser.com/a/1426661/174311).

Comment: On my machine, this command doesn't show any PCIe cards.  `Win32_PnPEntity` by itself shows all devices, but when you add the deviceProperties part it filters the list so that it's missing all my PCIe cards.